# joomla 3 - Sistema SEARCH não funciona

Tags: algoritmo-de-busca, joomla

Estou tentando usar o sistema de busca (search) do joomla-3 mas acaba sempre dando este erro:

> **TPL_SEARCH_ERROR_SEARCH_NOT_FOUND**.

Alguém sabe me dizer do que se trata e como eu resolvo?

Comment: Primeiro a tradução do erro não está sendo carregada, acredito que esse não é o erro em si.